# Что за MIME тип "vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.имякомпании.типконтента"?

Tags: android-sdk

Объясните мне что это за MIME тип и как с ним работать?
Как я понял это нестандартный тип "от разработчика".

vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.имякомпании.типконтента
А для коллекции записей или строк MIME-тип выглядит так:
vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.имякомпании.типконтента
Вот пара примеров:
// Одна заметка
vnd.android.cursor.item/vnd.google.note
// Коллекция или каталог заметок
vnd.android.cursor.dir/vnd.google.note

Почему именно так? Есть какие-то условия?

"vnd.android.cursor.item" - почем именно cusor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7562509/android-content-type-is-vnd-android-cursor-dir-some-standard-constant-defined) есть объяснение.

Если очень коротко - в нем есть две части - `type/subType`.

Type - это либо `vnd.android.cursor.item` (если нужен один элемент) или `vnd.android.cursor.dir`, если нужен "список").

Вторая часть - это то, что понимает приложение и позволяет выбрать как обработать поступивший запрос. Тут уже на откуп программиста.

> "vnd.android.cursor.item" - почем именно cusor?

это от баз данных (контент провайдер является оболочкой к базе данных, не обязательно реально существующей). В базах данных, курсор - это такой себе указатель на запись.